# Are communities "Comfy" or "Compact" by default?

Tags: community, lightning-community, slds

This [Density Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/new-density-settings-for-the-lightning-experience-ui-in-winter-19.html) drives the sizes of the `var` [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/) classes e.g.:

```
Class Name                  Comfy Value Compact Value
slds-var-p-around_xxx-small 0.125rem    0.125rem
slds-var-p-around_xx-small  0.25rem     0.125rem
slds-var-p-around_x-small   0.5rem      0.125rem
slds-var-p-around_small     0.75rem     0.25rem
slds-var-p-around_medium    1rem        0.5rem
slds-var-p-around_large     1.5rem      0.75rem
slds-var-p-around_x-large   2rem        1rem
slds-var-p-around_xx-large  3rem        1.5rem
```

and the VSCode tooling prompts you to move to these `var` ones.

I assume Communities operate as "Compact" by default (but will check in a minute).

Any expectation that this density option will be offered to Communities users in the future?

**PS**

A `slds-var-m-bottom_medium` generates a 16px (that I think is 1rem) margin in a Community so it looks like "Comfy" is the default based on:

```
Class Name                  Comfy Value Compact Value
slds-var-m-*_medium         1rem        0.75rem
```